# Python find exact match in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know there have been similar questions but i couldn't find example close to mine.

```
file = open("id_list.txt")
ids = file.read()
user = 'admin'
if user not in ids:
   #do something
file.close()
```

This works fine with string like admin in the id_list.txt but will also work if the string is admin123 or rtadmin. I have tried

```
if user != ids:
```

with no luck

Comment: your `for` loop is syntactically incorrect. Also what is `data['queries']` in your code ?

Comment: Hey thanks for looking. data['queries'] is output of queries attribute in a json file. There is alot more to the code but I made this as simple as possible. If there is no simple solution i will have to rewrite my loop

Comment: I removed the loop as its not related

Comment: Now your code is incorrectly indented. Also what is `query`? It's not defined anywhere

Comment: fixed @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: use `ids = file.read().split()`  also remember to close the open file (or even better use `with`)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
with open('id_list.txt', 'r') as stream:
    ids = stream.read()
    words = ids.strip().split()
    keywords = ['admin','admin123','rtadmin']  
    for item in keywords:  
        if item not in ids:
            print("Do something")
```